# how to load .pcap file into java(swings)

Tags: java, sockets, wireshark

I'm currently working on my final year project which is J-HONEYPOT :- Java based intrusion detection and monitoring system. i had problem on after capturing packet from wireshark in extension of .pcap. i want to extract the file using java and store the information in Mysql DB.

Project idea video :- https://youtu.be/_nuS0lt2so8

Comment: yes intrusion detection .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a pure Java library for parsing pcap files (instead of one that relies on a native libpcap), then have a look at pkts.io: http://www.aboutsip.com/pktsio/.  E.g.

```
final Pcap pcap = Pcap.openStream("my_traffic.pcap");

pcap.loop(new PacketHandler() {
    @Override
    public void nextPacket(final Packet packet) throws IOException {
        if (packet.hasProtocol(Protocol.UDP)) {
            System.out.println(packet.getPacket(Protocol.UDP).getPayload());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: if i need IP address ,mac address, ttl and all tcp details so how i can get those details ???